# Plot the residual sum of squares on the best fit distribution's plot

Tags: python

I want to plot the residual sum of squares on the best fit distribution of this data.

[image: plot]

I got the best fit distribution but I'm failing to plot the rss with it.
After that I also wish to plot a function: RSS²/loc². Any idea, please?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import scipy.stats
import time
from numpy.random import randn


# Load data

L = np.linspace(5,1.0,210)
V = L + 0.02*randn(len(L))
data = np.exp(-3.0*L**2) + 0.1*randn(len(L))


### Histogramme des données
y, x = np.histogram(data, bins=50, density=True)

# Milieu de chaque classe
x = (x + np.roll(x, -1))[:-1] / 2.0

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.hist(data, bins=50, density=True)
plt.title("MOE")
plt.show()

#Lois candidates
dist_names = ['norm', 'beta','gamma', 'pareto', 't', 'lognorm', 'invgamma',
              'invgauss',  'loggamma', 'alpha', 'chi', 'chi2']


sse = np.inf
sse_thr = 0.10

# Pour chaque distribution
for name in dist_names:

    # Modéliser
    dist = getattr(scipy.stats, name)
    param = dist.fit(data)

    # Paramètres
    loc = param[-2]
    scale = param[-1]
    arg = param[:-2]

    # PDF
    pdf = dist.pdf(x, *arg, loc=loc, scale=scale)
    # SSE
    model_sse = np.sum((y - pdf)**2)

    # Si le SSE est ddiminué, enregistrer la loi
    if model_sse < sse :
        best_pdf = pdf
        sse = model_sse
        best_loc = loc
        best_scale = scale
        best_arg = arg
        best_name = name

    # Si en dessous du seuil, quitter la boucle
    if model_sse < sse_thr :
        break

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(x, y, label="Données")
plt.plot(x, best_pdf, label=best_name, linewidth=3)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()

# Détails sur la loi sélectionnée
print("Selected Model : ", best_name)
print("Loc. param. : ", best_loc)
print("Scale param. : ", best_scale)
print("Other arguments : ", best_arg)
print("SSE : ", sse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically we cannot plot the sum of residual squares but we can with the residual squares. Take every value of the resulting best pdf and calculate rss (residual square) with the given y.

`rss_i = (y_i - bpdf_i)^2`

##### Code revision

```
# Record rss per best pdf values.
best_rss = []
best_rss_loc = []
for ay, bpdf in zip(y, best_pdf):
    rss = (ay-bpdf)**2  # residual square formula
    best_rss.append(rss)

    rss_loc = rss**2/best_loc**2
    best_rss_loc.append(rss_loc)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(x, y, label="Données")
plt.plot(x, best_pdf, label=best_name, linewidth=3)
plt.plot(x, best_rss, label='best rss', linewidth=1)
plt.plot(x, best_rss_loc, label='best rss^2/loc^2', linewidth=1)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.yscale('symlog')
plt.ylabel('Y (symmetrical log scale)')
plt.show()
```

##### Plot

[image]

##### Reference

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares